# Outlook rules not working together

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I have multiple Outlook (2010) rules and these 2 are having issues together:

> Rule 1: Apply this rule after the message arrives with `blahname` in the sender's address and move it to the `BlahBox` folder.
>
> Rule 2: Apply this rule after the message arrives from `noreply@domain.com` move it to the NoReply folder.

If I have rule 1 above rule 2, only rule 1 works (noreply emails stay in the Inbox folder). If I swap and have rule 2 above rule 1, only rule 2 works (blahname emails stay in the Inbox folder).

What am I doing wrong; how can I fix this so it applies both rules on incoming email?

I'm fairly certain the two rules should never intersect (blahname != domain.com). Also I do not have "this computer only" checked on any rules, I avoid client-only rules.

"stop processing more rules" is not checked on either.

Comment: Is "this computer only" checked at the bottom of the window in Step 1? That can sometimes cause issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB It is not.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook applies the first rule that meets criteria, and then stops processing further rules. If you need multiple rules for the same criteria, then you either need to separate the criteria, or find some other way to handle the emails.

It appears you have some overlap in your rules that causes this (For example both are using from domain. Try splitting one to from specific person, and not using the domain rule for the noreply@domain.com.

Comment: Under actions for both rules, there is a `stop processing more rules` checkbox. I have this unchecked for both rules, so wouldn't it not stop processing further rules?

Comment: Kind of, sort of. But if you have a message from noreply@domain and you delete it, for example... you can't then expect the email which also meets the criteria of from *domain* to be moved to another folder. Outlook has some rules that will stop further processing, period. If you share your exact rules (Change names is fine) maybe we can workout the full problem.

Comment: In that case since you have that option unchecked, once either of the rules fire, it moves the message to another folder, so none of the other rules that affect messages in the Inbox would fire afterwards, hence why only the first one works.

Comment: @AthomSfere The rules above are copy-paste from my Rule window, aside from changing the names.

Comment: @Taegost But the rules never apply to the same message; `domainname` never exists within the other rule (`domain.com`). They should never touch the same emails. I edited my post a bit to clarify.

Comment: Ah, ok gotcha, thanks for clarifying.  Unfortunately I don't have any further insight, I actually have the exact same problem, but it has to do with color-coding :)